# Adding decays to time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

Working with my time series data I need to add decays to a certain
variables. That is, when the variable consists of a series of
impulses, I need to prolong these effects of these in order to better
depict the true underlying nature of the effect.

I would also like to experiment with different types of decay lengths
(number of observations before cut-off) and types (e.g. linear and
exponential). Moreover, the code should be able to cope with summing
decays when impulses are within each others decay length.

Demo data

```
time  impulse
 1      0
 2    100
 3      0
 4      0
 5      0
 6      0
 7      0
 8    200
 9    100
10      0
11      0
12      0
13      0
14      0
15      0
16      0
17      0
18     60
19      0
20      0
```

Comment: Are decay lengths known?

Comment: @curious_cat: Yes they are. I commented on this in an answer (but he apparaently deleted if since it was wrong).

Comment: Figaro - you can edit your question to add new information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the R `dlnm` package will do what you want. It's the Distributed Lag Nonlinear Model package, that lets you specify lags and decays and then use lm, etc.

EDIT: I believe you'd do something like this:

```
library (dlnm)

my_delayed <- crossbasis (my_pulse, lag=10, argvar=list (df=3), arglag=list (df=3))
my_lm <- lm (my_dependent ~ my_delayed)
my_pred <- crosspred (my_delayed, my_lm, cumul=TRUE)

summary (my_pred)
plot (my_pred, "overall")
```

Look at the `crossbasis` documentation, you can adjust the degrees of freedom and the type for across the variable's range (argvar) or across time (arglag).

Comment: The `dlnm` package is quite extensive, happen to have an example?

Comment: What data does `my_dependent` represent?